# Close keyboard on a multi-line form (Pixel2)

Tags: forms, flutter

Messing around with flutter and I must be missing it in the documentation somewhere because I'm not sure what this object or property is.

I am trying to use a multiline textformfield, and so to handle focus I've used

onTap: (){FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());},

What I've noticed is that I need to doubletap to reenter the form field now.

When I do double tap, I get this odd label/hint -- How can I remove or prevent it from showing?

[Hint/Label?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGhUx.png)

Any info is appreciated :)

Edit: The reason I needed to double tap was because multi-line form fields switch the Pixel2 GO button to the newline button and prevents the user from exiting the keyboard cleanly.

Fixed by adding textInputAction: TextInputAction.go to the textformfield

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have the TextFormField work normally, you don't have to write your own onTap function. The built-in one works perfectly fine :)

Comment: Hmm I could be wrong, but it works fine without multiline. Once multiline is introduced the keyboard wont go away. I think it may be device specific. I am emulating on a Pixel2, when I change to multiline form field, the keyboard changes checkmark icon to a nextline icon.

Comment: I think I found the solution. I can edit the keyboard by using textInputAction: TextInputAction.go.... no longer need to edit the onTap function :) I think i will use the built-in functionality :)